# Parametrizing backend in terraform on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, cloudbuild.yaml

```
terraform {
    required_version = ">= 0.13"
    required_providers {
          google = {
           source = "hashicorp/google
           version = "~> 4.9.0"
        }
    }
   backend = "gcs" {
        bucket = "my-bucket"
        prefix = "/tfstate/{_NONLIVE_OR_LIVE}/{country}"
   }
}
```

I try to parametrize "terraform init" so that I can use the same main.tf file for six different use cases (_PREPROD_OR_PROD can be either pre-prod or prod; country can be either Portugal, Italy or Spain).

In the cloudbuild.yaml file I have to the same terraform_apply.yaml file for all six usecases and I want to specify it like "terraform init -backend-config="PREPROD_OR_PROD=${_PREPROD_OR_PROD}" -backend-config="{COUNTRY=${_COUNTRY}"

How can I implement this in terraform and Google Cloud/ GCP?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using the `-backend-config` properly, see [Partial configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration#partial-configuration) for more details.

You should use with with this format:

```bash
terraform init -backend-config="KEY=VALUE"
```

Where:

- `KEY` is the configuration option to set (like `prefix` or `bucket`)
- `VALUE` is the value to set it to (like
  `/tfstate/{_NONLIVE_OR_LIVE}/{country}`).

Consider the following backend:

```hcl
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "foobar.tfstate"
  }
}
```

I can change the `path` using the following command:

```bash
terraform init -backend-config="path=./dev.tfstate"

ENVIRONMENT="prod"
terraform init -backend-config="path=./$ENVIRONMENT.tfstate"
```

This will generate a `prod.tfstate` in the local folder.

Now, back to your code:

```hcl
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "foo"
    prefix = "bar"
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this but I suppose you can do something like:

```bash
BUCKET="my-bucket"
ENVIRONMENT="pre-prod"
COUNTRY="Portugal"

terraform init \
  -backend-config="bucket=$BUCKET" \
  -backend-config="prefix=/tfstate/$ENVIRONMENT/$COUNTRY"
```

As an alternative, you can use [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) to automatically generate the remote backend for each environment.